# Show related data from two schemas in the same eex template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to show some related data in a form. I have a Students schema

```
schema "students" do
  field :firstname, :string
  field :lastname, :string
  field :birthday, Ecto.Date
  field :joined_on, Ecto.Date
  field :gender, :string
  timestamps()
end
```

Each student can have a mother and a father, these I have designated them as Parents and created a separate schema and separate table. Each parent record can be linked with max 1 student (odd, but works for my use case).

```
schema "parents" do
  field :relationship, :string
  field :fullname, :string
  field :qualification, :string
  belongs_to :student, Myapp.Student, foreign_key :student_id
  timestamps()
end
```

I am trying to create a form where I can create new Students and Parents at the same time. So there will be fields for Student and fields for Mother and Father in the same form. I've tried multiple ways to get this Parents data in the eex template but I'm failing at it.

Here is what I'm using in the `new` method of the `Student` controller:

```
def new (conn, _params) do
  changeset = Student.changeset(%Student{})
  render(conn, "new.html", [changeset: changeset])
end
```

I think there's something wrong here because I'm not able to get the `parents` fields in the eex form when I use the Html helpers. I want to be able to create new students, parents at the same time. Also it would be great if I can edit them using the same eex template. Thanks.

Comment: The first obvious thing you're missing is `has_many :parents, Myapp.Parent` in the `students` schema. Does that solve your problem? If not, can you post the eex form code you tried?

Comment: Thanks. Yes missing that and a few more things from the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `has_many` and `cast_assoc` in `Student` model:

```
defmodule Myapp.Student do
  use Myapp.Web, :model

  schema "students" do
    field :firstname, :string
    field :lastname, :string
    field :birthday, Ecto.Date
    field :joined_on, Ecto.Date
    field :gender, :string
    has_many :parents, Myapp.Parent

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:firstname, :lastname, :birthday, :joined_on, :gender])
    |> cast_assoc(:parents)
    |> validate_required([:firstname, :lastname, :birthday, :joined_on, :gender])
  end
end
```

In `web/templates/student/form.html.eex` use `inputs_for`:

```
<%= inputs_for f, :parents, fn pf -> %>
  <h3>Parent form</h3>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label pf, :relationship, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input pf, :relationship, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag pf, :relationship %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label pf, :fullname, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input pf, :fullname, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag pf, :fullname %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label pf, :qualification, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input pf, :qualification, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag pf, :qualification %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You can build two parents in Student controller action `new`:

```
alias Myapp.Parent

def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = Student.changeset(%Student{parents: [%Parent{}, %Parent{}]})
  render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
```

Also need to preload `:parents` in `StudentController` for `edit` and `update` actions:

```
student = Repo.get!(Student, id) |> Repo.preload(:parents)
```

The code - https://github.com/shhavel/stackoverflow-questions-39683691

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this in detail! I'm starting to grok how Ecto works